# Перемещение внутри <select>

Tags: javascript, php, select

Имеется HTML-код:

```html
<select class="select" onchange="window.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="URL-1" class="1">Привет</option>             <!-- RU -->
<option value="URL-2" class="2">Сәлеметсіз</option>         <!-- KZ -->
<option value="URL-3" class="3">Salom</option>              <!-- UZ -->
<option value="URL-4" class="4">Салом</option>              <!-- KR -->
<option value="URL-5" class="5">Салам</option>              <!-- TJ -->
<option value="URL-6" class="6">Salam</option>              <!-- TM -->
</select>
```

Хотел бы в виде триггера использовать вложенность папки по URL. Пример: https://www.site.com/kz/page/

Соответственно имеется PHP-код:

```html
$lang_page = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[-1]  ?? 'ru';
$trans['page-kz'] = ['kz' => '1'];
```

Результат получаю в нужном месте с помощью:

```html
'.$trans['page-ru'][$lang_page].'
```

Но, хотел бы получить следующий конечный результат. Если это страница: https://www.site.com/kz/page/ то, в начало списка выводить как активную часть: Сәлеметсіз, вот пример (сравните с выше показанным HTML):

```html
<select class="select" onchange="window.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="URL-2" class="2">Сәлеметсіз</option>         <!-- KZ -->
<option value="URL-1" class="1">Привет</option>             <!-- RU -->
<option value="URL-3" class="3">Salom</option>              <!-- UZ -->
<option value="URL-4" class="4">Салом</option>              <!-- KR -->
<option value="URL-5" class="5">Салам</option>              <!-- TJ -->
<option value="URL-6" class="6">Salam</option>              <!-- TM -->
</select>
```

- Пожалуйста помогите с решением (если возможно на PHP или в крайнем случае на JS). Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Решение на JS

```
<select class="select" onchange="window.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="URL-1" class="1" data-lang="ru">Привет</option>
    <option value="URL-2" class="2" data-lang="kz">Сәлем</option>
    <option value="URL-3" class="3" data-lang="uz">Salom</option>
    <option value="URL-4" class="4" data-lang="kr">Салом</option>
    <option value="URL-5" class="5" data-lang="tj">Салам</option>
    <option value="URL-6" class="6" data-lang="tm">Salam</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let selectEl = document.querySelector(".select");
    let lang, langPos, loc = window.location.href;
    let options = selectEl.options;
    let newOptions = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        lang = '/'+options[i].dataset.lang+'/';
        langPos = loc.indexOf(lang);
        if (langPos > 0) {
            newOptions.push(options[i]);
            selectEl.removeChild(options[i]);
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < newOptions.length; j++) {
        selectEl.insertBefore(newOptions[j], options[0]);
        options[0].selected = true;
    }
</script>
```